# Using SSRS reportitems to create percentage

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have two textboxes, part of a larger matrix, which calculate values based on summing lookups, with filter criteria.

I want to take the figures from each of them, divide one by the other and create a percentage, which will be used in a text string elsewhere in the report.

I can get the individual figures in the header for the relevant page (not ideal, should be in the body of the report) by referencing the report items in the matrix, however when I try to use both I get an error informing me of an apparently arbitrary restriction that 'An expression in a page header or footer can refer to only one report item'.

Attempting to do the calculation with report variables by passing the reportitems and then calculating gives the even less coherent error 'The Variable(blah) value expression used for the language of 'body' refers to a report item. Variable values cannot be used in report language expressions'.

Is there an easy way to do this without adding any extra cells to my original matrix? It seems like there is not much point having variables if you then have to add hidden textboxes in order to store your values.

Answer (score 0):

try doing all your calculations in sql itself and refer the fields in SSRS. i faced a similar issue recently and this is how i did.

Else try using VB code to do the calculations.

Comment: Some of the queries are not in SQL, they are in an MDX data cube, and I would prefer not to add hidden rows or columns to the matrix if I can help it. If the calculations are done in additional columns whether with vb.net expressions or anything else, then I can apparently only refer to them using reportitems from the header, which messes up the layout of the report even more. If I created additional SQL queries just to create the strings it would slow down the report and make the code messier.

Comment: you can use the code directly in the header - i have done it. adding more report items just to do calculations is not feasible. let me know if you were able to do it.

Comment: The text strings that I want to create will take up half a page, and if I do it in a header then a blank header will appear on every page. This is not how I want the report to look. It has to be sent elsewhere in my organisation.

Comment: try this - do all the calculations in vb code - create new parameters for each code call (hide the parameters) - refer the parameters in the header or body - wherever you need them.